# Magento 1.9 - Looking for Sample CSV customer import File

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer-account, importexport

Anyone can help me with the sample CSV format to import the "customers" from backend??

When I tried to import the exported file from 
`Admin > Customers > Export To > CSV`. 
It is showing the error like

> Can not find required columns: email, _website.

Which means headers need to be changed ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System** -> **Import/Export** -> **Dataflow profiles**.
*(NOT to Magento admin->System->Import/Export->Import!)*

Then, select profile: **Import Customers** (or create if it not exists).

Set the Store value in the Profile information box to the '**Default store view**'. Then, upload Your CSV, and run the profile.

You can use the CSV header like below:

```
id  website firstname   lastname    email   password_hash   billing_firstname   billing_lastname    billing_company billing_postcode    billing_city    billing_street1 billing_telephone   billing_country billing_region  shipping_firstname  shipping_lastname   shipping_company    shipping_postcode   shipping_city   shipping_street1    shipping_telephone  shipping_country    shipping_region is_subscribed   group   group_id    dob
```

Comment: Why NOT to Magento admin->System->Import/Export->Import. Can you please clarify???